# DropDownListFor not pre-selecting value from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller Code:

```
AccountsDetailsViewModel vOwnerVM = Mapper.Map<VehicleOwner, AccountsDetailsViewModel>(vOwner);
AccountsDetailsAccountViewModel vOwnerDetailsVM = Mapper.Map<VehicleOwner, AccountsDetailsAccountViewModel>(vOwner);

ViewBag.FleetType = new SelectList(VehicleOwnerFleetTypeFactory.GetTypes().OrderBy(l => l.Type), "Id", "Type");
vOwnerVM.AccountDetails = vOwnerDetailsVM;
```

Main ViewModel Code:

```
public class AccountsDetailsViewModel
{
    public AccountsDetailsAccountViewModel AccountDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Main View Code

```
@model X.Views.Accounts.ViewModels.AccountsDetailsViewModel
@Html.Partial("DetailsAccount", @Model.AccountDetails)
```

Partial ViewModel Code:

```
[DisplayName("Fleet Type")]
public int FleetType { get; set; }
```

Partial View Code

```
@model X.Views.Accounts.ViewModels.AccountsDetailsAccountViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FleetType, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FleetType)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FleetType) (FOR DEBUG)
```

VehicleOwnerFleetType class

```
public class VehicleOwnerFleetType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleOwnerFleetTypeFactory
{
    static readonly VehicleOwnerFleetType[] Types = new VehicleOwnerFleetType[] {

            new VehicleOwnerFleetType() {Id = 0, Type = "Unknown"},
            new VehicleOwnerFleetType() {Id = 1, Type = "HGV"},
            new VehicleOwnerFleetType() {Id = 2, Type = "Car"},
            new VehicleOwnerFleetType() {Id = 3, Type = "Van"},
            new VehicleOwnerFleetType() {Id = 4, Type = "Mixed"}
        };

    public static VehicleOwnerFleetType[] GetTypes()
    {
        return Types;
    }

    public static VehicleOwnerFleetType GetType(int id)
    {
        return Types.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Regardless of what the database shows, the dropdown does not display the correct value from the model, only ever the top value in the list.

However if I select a value and then submit the form to save the changes to the database, it does submit the correct value.

When returning the view of the viewmodel in the controller, the values mirror the database exactly, I cannot figure out why it is doing this.

Edit: The 'Sectors' dropdown is the ONLY one that auto-selects the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by the fact that your selectlist, and your VM's member variable have the same names.

```
model.FleetType
```

and

```
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FleetType
```

Try to rename the select list to FleetTypeList or similar

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. Check if you pass the model to the view.

```
@using WebApplication2.Controllers
@model WebApplication2.Controllers.MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    ViewBag.FleetType = new SelectList(
        VehicleOwnerFleetTypeFactory.GetTypes().OrderBy(l => l.Type),
        "Id", 
        "Type");
}

<div>
    <h2>---------------------------</h2>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FleetType,
            (SelectList)ViewBag.FleetType)
    <h2>---------------------------</h2>
</div>
```

and

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new MyModel { FleetType = 2 });
        }
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        public int FleetType { get; set; }
    }

    public class VehicleOwnerFleetTypeFactory
    {
        public static FleetType[] GetTypes()
        {
            return new[]
                {
                    new FleetType {Id = 1, Type = "Type 1"},
                    new FleetType {Id = 2, Type = "Type 2"},
                    new FleetType {Id = 3, Type = "Type 3"}
                };
        }
    }

    public class FleetType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention. It is inside a partial view. I am going to edit my answer above to show the code involved.

Comment: @Seb check in debug if your partial view has right model

Comment: It definitely is, as the SectorId updates properly (that is pulling values directly from the database) but all the selectlists that pull their values from the factories don't.

I can even DisplayFor the values and they are correct, so the problem is in the selectlist somewhere!

Comment: @Seb Could you provide clean sample with FleetType related code only (including main an partial view). Contact me if you have troubles

Comment: I can yes, shall I put it all in the first question?

Comment: @Seb yes, would be great

Comment: Ok, I've added a few more bits now - does that help at all?

If you see, I've put in the 'DisplayFor' next to the dropdown, which actually shows the correct values! So the displayfor shows a value of 5, but the dropdown has not pre-selected option 5, it just starts at the top.